# WCF Debugging Not Finding Method

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, rest

Debugging WCF - and for the life of me I cannot figure out why my service method is returning http error 400.  The DLL is deployed in IIS and the SVC points to it - all of the other service methods in the DLL are available and return the correct data.  I have the debugger attached in the process in IIS, and I am able to step through all of the other service methods - but for some reason the debugger doesn't even catch calls to this method.   Symbols are loaded correctly.  I even tried breaking on all exceptions - it does not want to stop in GetCustomInquiries_POST for any reason, and the service is still available and shows http error 400 on return.  Any ideas?  I know I fat fingered it somewhere.

I have a service with the following contract:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Stream GetCustomInquiries_POST();
```

And the following implementation:

```
    public Stream GetCustomInquiries_POST()
    {
        // Returns a list of of business objects
        CustomInquiries customInquiries = WebSupport.DocumentInquiry.GetCustomInquiries();

        // Create an empty list of WCFCustomInquiry, which is a data
        // contract that exposes certain properties of a customInquiry.  
        // This list will be filled with all of the saved inquiries
        List<WCFCustomInquiry> customInquiriesToReturn = new List<WCFCustomInquiry>();

        // For each of the inquiries that were returned.
        foreach (CustomInquiry customInquiry in customInquiries)
        {

            // Create a list of properties exposed via the web service
            List<WCFProperty> savedProperties = new List<WCFProperty>();

            // For each of the properties in the saved inquiry, cast it to a WCFProperty, 
            // which is added to the list of properties exposed to the web service
            foreach (InquiryPropertyValue testProperty in customInquiry.SearchCriteria.Properties.Values)
            {
                WCFProperty savedProperty = new WCFProperty(testProperty.PropertyID, testProperty.Prompt, testProperty.DataType);
                savedProperty.inquirySearchText = testProperty.Value.ToString();
                savedProperty.inquirySearchType = testProperty.SearchType;
                savedProperties.Add(savedProperty);
            }


            // create a new webInquiryCriteria instance, which exposes the listed
            // properties to the web service.
            WCFInquiryCriteria webInquiryCriteria = new WCFInquiryCriteria(customInquiry.TopLevelFolders, customInquiry.DocTypes, customInquiry.SearchCriteria.DocumentTypes, customInquiry.SearchCriteria.TopLevelFolders, savedProperties, "", "", false, null, null);

            // Created an instance of the data-contract, using the members
            // to be exposed from the inquiry
            WCFCustomInquiry customInquiryToReturn = new WCFCustomInquiry(customInquiry.CustomInquiryId, customInquiry.Name, customInquiry.Description, customInquiry.AutoRun, customInquiry.DocTypes, customInquiry.TopLevelFolders, webInquiryCriteria, customInquiry.UserSuppliedProperties);

            // Add that new instance to the list that 
            customInquiriesToReturn.Add(customInquiryToReturn);
        }

        return WebSupport.JSONSerializationHelper.GetJSONStreamToReturn(customInquiriesToReturn);
    }
```

Comment: Via REST - HTTP POST - I can write an ajax method but for testing I normally use XHR Poster for chrome.  So I can post to http://192.168.23.102/website/DocumentInquiry_REST.svc/GetCustomInquiries_POST and I get error 400 - but if I post to http://192.168.23.102/DocumentInquiry_REST.svc/GetSavedInquiries_POST I get a json list of items as expected.